# My Macbook pro retina screen is dead

Tags: mac, macbook-pro

I own a macbook pro retina, mid 2012. I bought like 2 years and 2 months ago.

Yesterday, I was cleaning my macbook as usual with some alcohol(95% ethanol), between the keys and on the screen. I do it regularly and it's my first time.

After a bit, the screen started flickering in a barely visible way, you need to focus on the screen to see the flickering, I directly updated OSX and restarted. After the restart, the flickering increased and it became clear. I turned off my mac for about an hour and tried to boot. The flickering disappeared but after 10 minutes the flickering got back. I was shocked, so I turned it off till the next day. Once I woke up I turned it on and noticed that there were no flickering. I left it on for about an hour and when I came back to check the flickering was enormous, there were color changes,  it felt like the screen was going to blow. I turned it off and rebooted and the screen was dead.

Here's an image of what I currently get when I boot

[image]

I tried an external display with both vgas, and everything worked fine.

Is this a screen problem? or a mobo problem? any other explanation to the above image?

A $3k macbook with an LG screen (with ghosting, yes I managed those 2 years with it) and that's what I get? I live outside the US, I bought it from the US and the Apple official retail stores here in my country do not honor the Apple warranty, they have their own.

Comment: As Buscar says, it looks like something got wet, turning the mac on made the problem worse. Next time immediately place the entire mac in rice while powered off for a day or two (you can still try this) as to what is damaged, the monitor or videocard: try making a screenshot of the damaged monitor and see if the problem shows up on that, if it does, its the videocard, if it doesn't it is the monitor or cables.

Comment: I took a screenshot, the screenshot was normal.

Comment: If it didn't show up on the screenshot it is not the videocard, but it can still be anything from the cables to the monitor itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple says:](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3226)

> Use only a soft, lint-free cloth. Abrasive cloths, towels, paper
>   towels, and similar items may cause damage to the item.
>
> Disconnect your Apple product from any external power sources.
>
> Disconnect any external devices and other cabling from the product.
>
> **Keep liquids away from the product.**
>
> Don't get moisture into any openings, and don't use aerosol sprays,
>   solvents, or abrasives.
>
> Do not spray cleaners directly onto the item.

You obviously managed to get liquid inside and on to your logic board.

Since it was mainly alcohol you might be lucky, by drying it for a while, but if the damage was done you are out of luck.

Comment: I see, but the soft napkin had barely any alcohol. Anyway, shit happens. What do you think is the problem? Is it from the screen or from the logic board? I was going to order a new screen from abroad.

Comment: I would guess it is the screen since the external monitor works, or just the data cable for the build in screen.

Answer (score 1):

If it's still in warranty try with the online assistance, don't mention the alcohol damage, obviously

Comment: Sadly, the warranty has expired. I ordered a new screen, hopefully it's a screen issue.

Comment: Doesn't really look like a display issue to me, but then again, I could be wrong. Here's a link to the iFixit teardown, hope this helps
https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_15%22_Retina_Display_Mid_2012